# Why 't Hooft says: field configuration in Euclidean space that have the vacuum (or a gauge transformation thereof) at the boundary

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-anomalies, instantons

In [Symmetry Breaking through Bell-Jackiw Anomalies G. 't Hooft, Phys. Rev. Lett. 37, 8 – Published 5 July 1976](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.37.8),

't Hooft said that the topological quantum number $n$

> $n$ is an integer for all field configuration in Euclidean space that have **the vacuum (or a gauge transformation thereof) at the boundary.**

I understand this $n$ is a quantized Euclidean soliton number.

### But what does he mean to say **"the vacuum (or a gauge transformation thereof) at the boundary"?**

- What is the vacuum at the boundary ?
- What is the gauge transformation at the boundary ?

[image]

Comment: see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/438286/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/317273/50583

Answer (score 4):

By `vacuum' he means a vanishing gauge field $A$ and by gauge transformation thereof he means some arbitrary $A$ which is related to the vanishing configuration by a non-Abelian gauge transformation. i.e. the formula for $A$ is something like (there are various conventions),
$$A_\mu=i U^\dagger\partial_\mu U.$$
where $U$ is a Euclidean spacetime dependent $SU(2)$ matrix.

The boundary of 4D Euclidean space is a 3-sphere, and mappings of the 3-sphere to $SU(2)$ break up into homotopy classes indexed by the integer $n$ in formula (2).